# After publishing to server, my application requires browser restart

Tags: jsp, web-applications, websphere, ibm-rad

Whenever I make changes to my java code and `PUBLISH` it, It requires me to `restart` my web browser. 
If I don't restart my browser and just refresh the page, I get `null pointer exception` and a stacktrace is printed in the UI page.

```
Is there something I can do, so that when I publish, I don't
have to restart my browser but my changes are still reflected?
```

This drains my efficiency.

However, if I just build it and refresh the page without publishing, then the page works fine. But my page may or may not reflect the changes I  have made.

```
I'm using Websphere server 7 and RAD 8.
```

**Error message:**

Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /jsp/myPage.jsp in application MY-APP. Exception created : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Are you using a session? If yes is this the NullPointer? look to create a new session (populated) if one is not available.

Comment: @Caleryn this is the error message I get:  Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /jsp/myPage.jsp in application MY-APP. Exception created : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Add the full stack trace to your question, and the code that causes the exception

Comment: @Taylor I think It's not code that's causing the problem. I could just add a sysout statement and publish it and I would still get NPE and would require to restart the browser. And after restart, it works fine. I'm assuming it's something to do with the server.

Comment: @Susie That's unlikely unless something in your code is trying to access something from request/session that's not there.

Comment: @Susie definitely sounds like a session problem to me too, have a look at how session management is configured in your Websphere server, potentially by default, try http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4580.pdf, It's not a server I know well. You may want to just turn it off if you can.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this is not much you're giving us here. And so everything I can do (as the man with white beard I am) is tell you a story from former days. Once upon a time on another app server, java version and browser I had a similar problem. It turned out, I had a non-serializable object in my session. Now when I re-deployed the application is stopped. So the running sessions are suspended to disc. And after the redeployment the server restarted those running sessions again. Unfortunately, because of those unserializable objects only just a part of the sessions and other parts stayed unexpectedly null. Now when I didn't restart the browser or (of course you already know it) cleared the cookies the browser connected to one of those partially initialized sessions and NPEed me.